# How to make bash alias invocation conditional on PWD?

Tags: bash, alias

I currently have this alias:

```
alias cmakerel='cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Wno-dev ../../ && make -j4'
```

Essentially, it will call cmake to do an `out-of-source` build from PWD.  It works fine, but as-is, it can be run from nearly anywhere (which I don't want).

**How do I modify this alias so that it runs if and only if the string `bld` is in my present working directory?**

I need this change because without it, I sometimes accidentally invoke this command from the tst directory or some other directory where I just cause a total mess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

So make it a shell function.

```
function cmakerel {
    if expr match "$PWD" '.*bld.*' >/dev/null ; then
        cmake -D....
    else
        echo "Wrong directory!"
    fi
}
```

It's a regular expression you can adjust to your needs.

Comment: Great tip!  I would give you +5 if I could.  TYVM.

Comment: btw, how should I modify `cmakerel` above to return some failure value so when I call `cmakerel && make check` the second part doesn't get called on failure?

Comment: @kfmfe04 Add a line `exit $?` below the `cmake` call. It will then exit with the exit code of the last command performed. Unless you use pipes, it's straightforward. Below the `echo` call, add `exit 1`.

Comment: great - thx!  Add this as an answer to the Question I just posted and so I can send you some points.