# How do I return a failure value from a bash function?

Tags: bash

#### Background

In this [posting](https://superuser.com/questions/368671/how-to-make-bash-alias-invocation-conditional-on-pwd), the following solution was posted:

```
function cmakerel {
    if expr match "$PWD" '*bld*' >/dev/null ; then
        cmake -D....
    else
        echo "Wrong directory!"
    fi
}
```

`cmakerel` will invoke a `cmake` command, if `PWD` has `bld` in its name.

However, I normally invoke this command like:  `cmakerel && make check`

#### Question

**How do I modify the code above so that it returns a value on failure such that the second part, `make check` does not get invoked?**

Probably returning some kind of non-zero value should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```
return $?
```

below the `cmake` call to exit the function with the same exit code as `cmake`, and add

```
return 1
```

below the `echo` call to exit with `1`, which is non-zero and therefore indicates an error.

---

You can alternatively (if you call both commands in combination) add the `make` call to this function:

```
 cmake [args] && make -j4
```

Or, to allow e.g. for more fine-grained error handling:

```
cmake [args]
local _ret=$?
if [ $_ret -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "cmake returned with exit code $_ret, aborting!" >&2
   return $_ret
fi
make -j4
```

---

If you call it as a standalone program, i.e. store the function in a shell script, and invoke e.g. as

```
/path/to/cmakerel.sh
```

then you can use `exit` instead of `return` to abort the whole program/subshell.

Comment: oops - on failure, it exited from my shell!  Any alternative?

Comment: @kfmfe04 I thought you called this as a shell script program, my bad. You can always simply return without doing the next steps.

Comment: tyvm - works great!

Comment: @kfmfe04 There was a typo in one of the snippets I only just now fixed. Sorry about that.